# Make BIRT report using data from Gemfire cache

Tags: birt, gemfire

I am relatively new to both, BIRT and gemfire but I know the basics. Thought I wasn't able to find how BIRT can fetch data from gemfire cache.

Can someone please help me on the procedure or whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like BIRT uses JDBC (amongst other means) to talk to a backend datasource. Unfortunately GemFire does not provide a JDBC driver. You would need to develop a custom ODA Data Source as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Use_Case_-_Create_a_Custom_ODA_Data_Source